# Android, ScrollView shows more space

Tags: android, scrollview

this is my code that the inside `ScrollView` shows more space for it's `TextView`, how can I fix it? I checked both `fillViewport` true and false and didn't work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/details_root_layer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/detail_header"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#900" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/pizza"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_details_header"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_no"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_details_header"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:textColor="#767676" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_price_text"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_price_text"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="12000"
        android:textColor="#666" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_details_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_details_uper_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#900" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_details_ok"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back_btn_details"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/OK"
            android:textColor="#900"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll_details_btn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_price"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/combnation"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="@string/Desc"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove `android:fillViewport="false"` and change width and height to `fill_parent` n try

Comment: widht is match_parent.. u want to fix hwight or wrap content?

Comment: the space i said is vertical !

Answer (score 0):

change your scroll view from

this:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/ll_details_btn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_price"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fillViewport="false" >
```

to this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```